# select from two tables and always return from one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have Mysql Database, with two tables, one with two key values, and the second one related to it 1 to N.

the first table always have data, but the second table related to it may not have.
I need to always return data from the first one, independent if  theres none in the second table.

Heres my query :

```
select a.*, b.* FROM disp_ofer a, ofer_detl b 
WHERE 
a.esta_cod = 'Lelis' 
AND
a.disp_ofer_data = '2013-10-30 16:07:20'
AND 
b.disp_ofer_data = a.disp_ofer_data
AND
b.esta_cod = a.esta_cod
```

Comment: Use a `left join`. Plus, I assume that by _"with two key values"_ you really mean _one composite primary key_, right?

Comment: @darkman You shouldn't just select answers based on reputation or votes. My answser is better formatted and has more content. May I ask you why you selected the other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) syntax... to join tables.

In your case, a LEFT JOIN.

```
select a.*, b.* FROM disp_ofer a
Left join ofer_detl b  
     on b.disp_ofer_data = a.disp_ofer_data and b.esta_cod = a.esta_cod
WHERE 
a.esta_cod = 'Lelis' 
AND
a.disp_ofer_data = '2013-10-30 16:07:20'
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use the [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) syntax rather than listing multiple tables in the `FROM` statement. It's considered a better practice.

A `LEFT JOIN` will allow you to achieve this goal. The `NATURAL` keyword will perform then join on all columns that exists in both tables automatically.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM disp_ofer a
NATURAL LEFT JOIN ofer_detl
WHERE a.esta_cod = 'Lelis' AND a.disp_ofer_data = '2013-10-30 16:07:20'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*, b.* 
FROM disp_ofer a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ofer_detl b ON (b.esta_cod = a.esta_cod AND b.disp_ofer_data = a.disp_ofer_data)
WHERE 
a.esta_cod = 'Lelis' 
AND
a.disp_ofer_data = '2013-10-30 16:07:20'
```

Comment: The `OUTER` keyword is not required.

Comment: yep, but gives understanding

Answer (score 0):

I propose you not just put a query from any answer to your code and forget about that subject, but to read and understand it. Joins are quite easy to understand and they are part of basics every web-developer should know. [This article](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) will help you, I hope.

Below goes my version of your query:

```
SELECT do.*, od.*
FROM disp_ofer do
LEFT JOIN ofer_detl od USING(ofer_data, esta_cod)
WHERE 
    do.esta_cod = 'Lelis' 
    AND do.disp_ofer_data = '2013-10-30 16:07:20'
```